# How to search for usage of types in specific assembly in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

For example, if an assembly references a library that includes many types, how can I use reflection to determine if the assembly uses a specific type in that referenced library.

If my library DLL has

```
public class LibraryClass1

public class LibraryClass2
```

but the assembly referencing the DLL only uses `LibraryClass1` (such as new `LibraryClass1()`) and not `LibraryClass2`, how can I determine that?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use-case? First of all every type referenced from another module will get an entry in the TypeRef (0x01) table in the assemblies metadata (Ecma 335 Partition II.22.38). But there is no built-in API to read that table. `Mono.Cecil` aswell as `dnlib` provide access to this information.

Comment: @thehennyy In this case the classes provided by the library implement a performance heavy initialization method and instead of initializing them all at startup, it's better to only initialize the ones being used by the service (they resolve as singletons so initialization is only done once). I'm not worried about the rare case where it might miss an initialization due to some exotic code since the initialization is done automatically on first use if not called explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to determine which class are loaded on the assembly you need to load it and get all types that are included and then make the question if you have an instance of that class that is used there.

Something like this

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies().Select(Assembly.Load);
    var definedTypes = assembly.SelectMany(a => a.DefinedTypes);
    var types = definedTypes.ToList().Select(dt => dt.AsType());

    var toRet = types.Any(t => t.IsClass && t.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(LibraryClass1)));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help if all the types are on a single assembly, since it returns all the types regardless of whether they're ever instantiated. Lets say I have 100 types in an assembly, but the consuming service using my library only uses 50 of these types. I only want to know those 50 types they are actually using. Mind you it's okay if types instantiated through reflection are missed (since that'd be impossible to tell).

Comment: ReferencedAssembly just tells you if you are using a reference of a class on your code from that assembly. That reference is an explicit reference. Also if you are writing the code of your new assembly you are the one that knows which clases you are using from the referenced one. But if you want to do the discovery via reflection. On your own assembly you should create a naming convention that you can use to discriminate the classes you are using. That will be my suggestion to make the classes more discoverables

Comment: That's my point though, I want to automate calling an initialization function on all types used in the current running assembly, but those types may come from the referenced assembly. I DO NOT want to call that initialize function on all types in that referenced assembly, I only want to initialize types actually used in my running assembly in an automated fashion. This is because this automation will be applied to hundreds of microservices across countless repos, not just a single service, so it has to be transparent to the user.